# Cannot access running django server?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I've created a docker image for django rest project, with following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` file,

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt /

# Install dependencies.
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# Set work directory.
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy project code.
COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8000
```

`docker-compose` file

```
version: "3"

services:     
  dj:
    container_name: dj
    build: django
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./django:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

And `docker-compose up` command bring up the server like this,

[image: server-is-up]

but in web browser i can't access the server, browser says `ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID`

Docker version 18.09.2

Comment: What URL are you using?  What error do you get?  What version/flavor of Docker do you have?

Comment: i'm using this as url `http://0.0.0.0:8000` and browser says site can't reached

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is IPv4 for "everywhere"; you can't usually make outbound connections to it.  If you have a Docker Desktop application, try `http://localhost:8000`; if it's Docker Toolbox, you'll need the `docker-machine ip` address, usually `http://192.168.99.100:8000`.

Comment: @DavidMaze got it, `http://localhost:8000` url worked ! thanx, but question is in `docker-compose` file defined `0.0.0.0:8000` and once i tried to `127.0.0.1` it says permission denied. Why is that ?

Comment: Each container has its own notion of `localhost`.  If you set a process in a container to only listen on the container's `localhost`, it will not accept any traffic from outside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 0.0.0.0 is IPv4 for "everywhere"; you can't usually make outbound connections to it. If you have a Docker Desktop application, try http://localhost:8000; if it's Docker Toolbox, you'll need the docker-machine ip address, usually http://192.168.99.100:8000.

thanks to David Maze problem is solved.

Comment: but, I am using http://127.0.0.1:8000/ still I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. what can I do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the django version 4.2 to 4.0, my app is running well in docker container.